# Manipulate Float Order CSS on mobile

Tags: html, css

I would like to float an image theoretically to right on desktop with the text next to it. Right now i have a div codeblock that has a bkgd of red and height and width of 100px. On mobile, I'd like to stack the text first and the image floated to the right underneath it. I haven't been able to achieve this with floating or clearing. Does anyone know a way I can do this without absolute positioning?

```css
#float1 {
  float: right;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:365px) {
  
  #float1 {
    float: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="float1">float one </div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum doloribus laborum harum non? Quod omnis nemo, doloribus fuga, perferendis sed officiis magnam magni adipisci. Odio fugiat, libero asperiores aut iure?</p>
```

Comment: wrap it all in a div and just use the flex box to do it.

Comment: i updated my question, there is a red div with a width of 100px

Comment: Flexbox would be the optimum method here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `flex` or `grid` instead `float` , you can use [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) :

> The `order` CSS property sets the order to lay out an item in a flex or grid container. Items in a container are sorted by ascending order value and then by their source code order.

example with a `flex` container + `order`.

```css
#float1 {
  order: 1;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

p {
flex:1;
/* default order is 0;*/
}

section {/* it could be body, but i think you better use a container */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width:365px) {
  p {
    flex-basis:100%;/* it will use the whole width, flex children will wrap */
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="float1">float one </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum doloribus laborum harum non? Quod omnis nemo, doloribus fuga, perferendis sed officiis magnam magni adipisci. Odio fugiat, libero asperiores aut iure?</p>
</section>
```

*usefull link* https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You should just use flexbox to achieve it.

You would have something like this in the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="float1">float one </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum doloribus laborum harum non? Quod omnis nemo, doloribus fuga, perferendis sed officiis magnam magni adipisci. Odio fugiat, libero asperiores aut iure?</p>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
#float1 {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

@media screen and (max-width:365px) {
    .wrapper {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```

Hope that gives you a starting point towards achieving the result:)

P.S. This is not tested. But it should work

Answer (score -1):

i think your code is true but you must change order Html Code Like this

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum doloribus laborum harum non? Quod omnis nemo, doloribus fuga, perferendis sed officiis magnam magni adipisci. Odio fugiat, libero asperiores aut iure?</p>
<div id="float1">float one </div>
```